# Tried '--net = host' and '- p: 50000:50000', but the container still has no binding port

Tags: docker, db2

I have use two ways to bound the port between host and container and all of them not display port.

1. --net=host

`docker run -it -d --name db2 --net host  -v /data/db2/db2inst1:/db2inst -e DB2INST1_PASSWORD=password -e LICENSE=accept 172.16.1.99/studio/common_db/db2-express-c:10.5 bash`

2. -p 50000:50000

`docker run -it -d --name db2 -p 50000:50000  -v /data/db2/db2inst1:/db2inst -e DB2INST1_PASSWORD=password -e LICENSE=accept 172.16.1.99/studio/common_db/db2-express-c:10.5 bash`

When i run docker ps -a All status of them are 'up', but not display anything in ports.

[image]

I also tried `docker port <container id>`, still nothing.

Comment: With the ending `bash` on your commands, you tell the container to run bash rather than the database. Since the database isn't running, there's nothing listening on port 50000.

Comment: This appears to be a duplicate: https://stackoverflow.com/q/71451379/596285

Comment: I didn't provide pictures for the previous one. I added it again after the question was closed.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried other methods. Take Mongo as an example, but it still doesn't show port.

```docker run -itd --name mongo -p 27017:27017 mongo --auth```

Comment: Please edit the previous question to include any required application source code or other artifacts to demonstrate the issue.  You generally shouldn't ask the same question again, or include screen shots of terminal windows in your question.

Answer (score -1):

is the port you're talking about exposed in your dockerfile ?

Comment: That doesn't matter. EXPOSE is for documentation and doesn't actually do anything.

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion. I tried other methods. Take Mongo as an example, but it still doesn't show port.

```docker run -itd --name mongo -p 27017:27017 mongo --auth```

Comment: @procrastinator101 this does not seem to answer the question, you can comment on the OP's question instead.